# How to get data by dynamic collection name in nodejs and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, angular8, mongoose-schema

Tried to get data from table by passing collection name dynamically but not working.I have two table[shoptable and markettable] and same header data.I want to get data depends on passing collection name.I do not know how to set schema for dynamic collection.Anyone can find wher i did mistake?

table.controller.js    //Nodejs

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const _ = require('lodash');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


let dynamicModels = {};
const ConvForUserSchema = new Schema({
    product_name: {
        type: String
    },
    price: {
        type: String
    },
    catogery: {
        type: String
    }
}, {
    versionKey: false,
    strict: false
});

const dynamicModel = (collectionName) => {
    if (!(collectionName in dynamicModels)) {
        dynamicModels[collectionName] = mongoose.model(collectionName, ConvForUserSchema, collectionName);
    }
    return dynamicModels[collectionName];
};


module.exports.getTableData = (req, res, next) => {

    let collection = req.query.collection;
    console.log("col=" + collection)

    dynamicModel(collection).find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ss' + err);
            return
        }
        return res.json(docs);
    }) 

    }
```

user.service.ts:

```
getTableData(collection){ 
return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/getTableData?collection=${collection}`);
}
```

product.component.js:

```
shopDatas(){ 
 this.getProductsData('shoptable'); 
}
marketDatas(){ 
 this.getProductsData('markettable'); 
}

getProductsData(collection){ 
 this.userService.getTableData(collection).subscribe(
  res => {
    this.tableData =  res; 
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);

  }
);
```

}

product.component.html:

```
<button (click)="shopDatas()">Shop data</button>
<button (click)="marketDatas()">Market data</button>
```

Comment: Create a two separate mongoose schema for both collections and require both mongoose model in the controller and select model according to condition.

Comment: @Aabid:Can you update my code?

Answer (score -1):

```
const newCollection = mongoose.model("collectionName" , Schema)
  newCollection.find({} , (err, docs)=>{
    console.log(docs)
  })
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), it'll help you have a smoother start. :)